# write text file in res/raw folder

Tags: android, text-files, file-handling

I have a text file in folder res/raw name "pass.txt" and some data in it i want to delete this data and enter new data in it.... is it possible to write data on it?? otherwise what is correct path to store my text file so i can easily read/write data on it.... and what is the code to read and write data from it?? below is the code through which i can only read data from this text file

```
InputStream fr = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pass);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fr));
                    String s=br.readLine().toString().trim();
```

Comment: You cannot write a file to raw folder. Its read-only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources contained in your raw directory in your project will be packaged inside your APK and will not be writeable at runtime.

Look at Internal or External Data Storage APIs to read write files.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use Android internal storage to Read and write file ... as res/raw is only Read only..you can not change content at runtime.

Here is the code:

Create file

```
 String MY_FILE_NAME = “mytextfile.txt”;
// Create a new output file stream 
FileOutputStream fileos = openFileOutput(MY_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// Create a new file input stream.
FileInputStream fileis = openFileInput(My_FILE_NAME);
```

Read from file:

```
 public void Read(){
static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;
try {
            FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");
            InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

            char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
            String s="";
            int charRead;

            while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
                // char to string conversion
                String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
                s +=readstring;                 
            }
            InputRead.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Write to file:

```
public void Write(){
try {
        FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("mytextfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
        outputWriter.write("TEST STRING..");
        outputWriter.close();

        //display file saved message
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: openFileOutput and openFileInput not working showing an error

Comment: you have to import java.io.FileInputStream;
and import java.io.FileOutputStream;

Comment: also if you are not in Activity ...you have to write getApplicationContext() before openFile

Comment: you acceptance vote should come at last after u have tested the code and it works for you...not rapidly after just answering a question...